# I cannot update the first row table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

This my coding to display all data in table user.. the file name is admindisplay.php

```
<?php
//Establish Server Connection String

//Connect to database
include('server.php');
session_start();

//Query database and set result to variable
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM user");
//Generate Table
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>No</th><th>Name</th><th>Department</th><th>Date</th><th>Issue</th><th>Details</th><th>Assign Person</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$No = $row ['No'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['No'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Issue'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Details'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Assignperson'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Status'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"adminassign.php\" method=\"POST\">
Note:   <input type=\"text\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"100\" name=\"note\">

<label>Assign to:</label>
<select name=\"assign\">
<option value=\"\">-Choose-</option>
<option value=\"Adrian\">Adrian</option>
<option value=\"Trainee\">Trainee</option> 
</select>

<input name=\"Nos\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$No\">

<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Assign\"</td>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

And this is my coding to updated any row that I want.. File name is adminassign.php

```
<?php
//Establish Server Connection String
//Connect to database
include('server.php');

session_start();
$No = $_POST ['Nos'];
$Note = $_POST['note'];
$Assign  = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['assign']));

if($Assign=='Adrian')
{

mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Assignperson = 'Adrian'  WHERE No = '$No'");
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Note = '$Note'  WHERE No = '$No'");
echo "assign successful";

}

else
{

if($Assign=='Trainee')

{
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Assignperson = 'Trainee' WHERE No = '$No'");
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Note = '$Note'  WHERE No = '$No'");
echo "assign successful";

}
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<p><input type="submit" value="Log Out"> 

</form>

<form action="admindisplay.php" method="POST">
<p><input type="submit" value="Back">

 </form>
```

The problem now is, I can only update the last row, the previous row cannot be updated. Can anyone  help me to solve this?

Comment: You are literally torturing php to echo so much of HTML

Answer (score 0):

Yeah  that is simple you have to use this

```
<input name=\"Nos\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$No\">
```

Whenever you submitting this they have submit last record data so you can use alternative for that one

```
<td><a href='adminassign.php?id=<?php echo $row['No']; ?>'>Edit</a></td>
```

This may helpful to you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You miss closing tag for each form in each row in your table:

```
</form>
```

Then, you have just one form with many Nos inputs and just the last one is considered.

The last line in the while cycle in your first code sample should be:

```
<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Assign\" /></form></td>";
```

You have also other syntax problems in your code (like missing closing brackets > ). This kind of problems can be caught by validator of html code: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Dev The closing tag isn't in the first code sample, thoug the opening one is in the while cycle.

Comment: If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider marking it as accepted. That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.